# Mule email attachment extension is null

Tags: mule, email-attachments, mule-component

I am able to send an email attachment using SMTP connector in MULE. But when my attachment arrives in "Inbox" it comes with ".null" extension.
If I open that file in notepad my expected data is present in the file.
I am unable to figure out why the extension is coming null. 
    My attachment looks like this 
    "MyFIle-01312019_0256.null"

```
This is my configuration
<set-attachment attachmentName="#[sessionVars.'channel-smtp-attachment-prefix']-#[server.dateTime.format('MMddyyyy_HHmm')].#[flowVars.'channel-smtp-attachment-extension']" value="#[payload]" contentType="#[flowVars.'channel-smtp-attachment-type']" doc:name="Mail Endpoint"/>

  And I set in code like this
   myObj.setAttribute("channel-smtp-attachment-prefix", REPORT_NAME_PREFIX);

  I tried following way 
  myObj.setAttribute("channel-smtp-attachment-prefix", REPORT_NAME_PREFIX + ".txt");

     Then my attachment looks like this
         MyFIle.txt-01312019_0256.null
```

I need ".txt" extension. Suggest me a way to do.